# Why do programming languages need to be adapted to be deployed on serverless

Tags: cloud, hosting, serverless

Laravel and php can be deployed on a traditional linux server, but to host it on serverless (AWS or Vercel) you need to use something like [bref](https://bref.sh/), why is that and what is bref exactly doing here.

similarly I can't just take my next.js app and host it on a traditional VPS. I looked it up online and it needs a special nginx configuration, whereas this wouldn't be needed when deploying on Vercel.

I understand that serverless is similar to a normal server, the difference is that it scales in memory and cpu power as your app grows in size. this says nothing about why laravel for instance can't run on serverless.